# Google e-commerce Scripts for Hotcakes e-commerce module

Tags: e-commerce, dotnetnuke

I am using Hotcakes e-commerce tools for my website. My website is using DNN platform.

Because I have 2 different websites and products need to track into Google e-commerce, therefore I need 2 set of Google e-commerce code.

One is `ga('ecommerce:send');` which is fine, the other one has to be `ga('Hatch.ecommerce:send');`

However Hotcakes does not allow me to modify Google e-commerce code. So I have to turn it off and edit it myself into the view model

I have implemented the code but it causes view error on the page.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

It gave this error message “An error has occurred. Error: Checkout is currently unavailable.”

This is the code for “receipt.cshtml”. I have added  near the bottom for Google e-commerce code:

```
@model Hotcakes.Modules.Core.Models.OrderViewModel
<div class="hc-receipt">
<h2>Thank you for purchasing</h2>
We know you will love creating beautiful embroidery designs with our Hatch products.<br /><br />
<a href="https://dyul59n6ntr4m.cloudfront.net/Hatch_Setup.exe">Click here to download Hatch Embroidery</a><br /><br />
<strong>You are not required to download Hatch If you purchased:</strong>
<ul>
<li>Additional Hatch add-ons</li>
<li>An UPGRADE to Embroidery Creator or Embroidery Digitizer</li>
<li>Hatch Fonts Packs</li>
</ul>
Simply RESTART the software for your new purchase to be available.<br />
Have fun and please share your creations with us on our <a href="https://www.facebook.com/wilcom" target="new">Facebook page</a><br />
@Html.Partial("_SetFirstPassword")
@Html.Partial("_ViewOrder", Model)
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
{
var item = Model.Items.ElementAt(i);
@item.ProductName
<span>@item.ProductSku</span><br />
**<script type="text/javascript">
ga('Hatch.ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '149428',
'affiliation': 'Hatch Embroidery Online Shop',
'revenue': '0',
'shipping': '0',
'tax': '@model.LocalOrder.TotalTax',
'city': '@model.LocalOrder.BillingAddress.City',
'state': '@model.LocalOrder.BillingAddress.RegionDisplayName',
'country': '@model.LocalOrder.BillingAddress.CountryDisplayName'
});
ga('Hatch.ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '@item.Id',
'name': '@item.ProductName',
'sku': '@item.ProductSku',
'category': 'Hatch Product',
'price': '@item.AdjustedPricePerItem',
'quantity': '@item.Quantity'
});
ga('Hatch.ecommerce:send');
</script>** 
}
</div>
```

I figured it has to be inside the loop if customer buying multiple products….
It will be great if you can give some hint or help with this…..
Thanks
Jack

Comment: For everyone's knowledge, this is using Hotcakes 01.10.03, right?

Comment: DNN Evoq Content 07.03.04 (45)
Hotcake 1.10.2
I will try change m to M see if that is gonna work..

Answer (score 1):

In looking at your code, there appeared to be some typo's in "Model" versus "model", additional spaces and characters in the script tag, and the product name wasn't being used correctly in the way that Razor expects to use it.  I'm not sure if this will fix all of the issues you encountered, but they appeared to all be Razor syntax and typo issues so far.

```
@model Hotcakes.Modules.Core.Models.OrderViewModel
<div class="hc-receipt">
    <h2>Thank you for purchasing</h2>
    We know you will love creating beautiful embroidery designs with our Hatch products.<br /><br />
    <a href="https://dyul59n6ntr4m.cloudfront.net/Hatch_Setup.exe">Click here to download Hatch Embroidery</a><br /><br />
    <strong>You are not required to download Hatch If you purchased:</strong>
    <ul>
        <li>Additional Hatch add-ons</li>
        <li>An UPGRADE to Embroidery Creator or Embroidery Digitizer</li>
        <li>Hatch Fonts Packs</li>
    </ul>
    Simply RESTART the software for your new purchase to be available.<br />
    Have fun and please share your creations with us on our <a href="https://www.facebook.com/wilcom" target="new">Facebook page</a><br />
    @Html.Partial("_SetFirstPassword")
    @Html.Partial("_ViewOrder", Model)
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = @Model.Items.ElementAt(i);
        <text>@item.ProductName</text>
        <span>@item.ProductSku</span><br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ga('Hatch.ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                'id': '149428',
                'affiliation': 'Hatch Embroidery Online Shop',
                'revenue': '0',
                'shipping': '0',
                'tax': '@Model.LocalOrder.TotalTax',
                'city': '@Model.LocalOrder.BillingAddress.City',
                'state': '@Model.LocalOrder.BillingAddress.RegionDisplayName',
                'country': '@Model.LocalOrder.BillingAddress.CountryDisplayName'
            });
            ga('Hatch.ecommerce:addItem', {
                'id': '@item.Id',
                'name': '@item.ProductName',
                'sku': '@item.ProductSku',
                'category': 'Hatch Product',
                'price': '@item.AdjustedPricePerItem',
                'quantity': '@item.Quantity'
            });
            ga('Hatch.ecommerce:send');
        </script>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Will,I have try to change all the Model to model, but it is still showng the same error. Can you help me with this in more details? I am new to this language.

Comment: Have you applied the updates in the answer?  There's more than just changing the "Model" references.

Comment: I have only changed the "model" to "Model", I dont know what else should I change....not sure how to use Product names.....

Comment: Please see and use the example in the answer.  

Using the product name correctly was a reference to using proper Razor syntax.

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c